# Сервер рандомно падает с ошибкой

Tags: c#, wcf

Пишу програмку на C# с использованием WCF. рандомно сервер падает с ошибкой:

[image: БАГ]

кроме скриншрта, не могу получить информации, т.к. баг происходит в не менеджмент коде и сервак виснет в ожидании мертвого потока.
исключение по стэку не поднимается, и отловить его не могу.
я понимаю, что информации маловато, но очень прошу помощи, т.к. идеи кончились и гугление не дало результатов.

пишите, какую информацию предоставить...
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 ENT
Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Тут читали -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386301/? Прямого ответа там нет, но может что-то натолкнет на идею.

Comment: читал, не натолкнуло.... но все равно спасибо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помог переход на 2012 сервер. UseSynchronizationContext =false.
всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, указатель `pOVERLAP` содержит какой-то мусор.

Скорее всего, при получении этого указателя для передачу в функции забыли использовать `fixed`-блок или какой-либо другой (более подходящий) способ блокирования объекта в памяти. Скорее всего, `fixed` тут не подходит.

Comment: Обратите внимание. На скриншоте - внутренности фреймворка, а не код автора.

Comment: да беда то в том, что это не я забыл. это программеры майкрософта, это их код. код самого WCF.

Comment: @Петр, тогда нужен минимальный пример кода, который приводит к ошибке.

Comment: могу хоть весь проект выложить, но конкретного места откуда происходит вызов я не могу найти. т.к. не могу получить стэктрэйс.

Comment: @Петр, почему не можешь? Что на вкладке стек вызовов?

Comment: пустота. был бы трейс было б проще...

Comment: @Петр снимите и выложите дамп.

Comment: как только грохнется выложу.

Comment: вот дамп: [ссылка](https://dropmefiles.com/WoELh)

Comment: @andreycha, это тебе :)

Comment: есть подозрение что оно падает при пиковых нагрузках. типа идет большое количество вызовов через wcf. может поможет переход на stream ? пиковая нагрузка несколько тысяч вызовов в секунду....

Comment: предположение не подтвердилось. сервак упал при отсутствии нагрузки.

Comment: это какая то мистика. баг появился, но приложение не упало. тестим дальше... были изменения: UseSynchronizationContext =false, client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout= TimeSpan.MaxValue; тут вобще есть ктонить ?

Comment: @Петр, чтобы тут кто-то был (из писавших комментарии), надо к нему и обращаться. Так уведомление получаю только я. Что делать с дампом, я не знаю. Кроме просьбы составить минимальный пример кода для воспроизведения ошибки, у меня идей нет.

Comment: @andreycha, а у тебя есть идеи? Что там дамп?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, буду знать. я заглядывал в дамп, не по силам мне такие вещи разбирать. но увидел что то связанное с потоками. есть идея, что ошибка это нормальна (в том плане, что ожидаема), но криво обработана. если не использовать контекст синхронизации, то она рушит только свой поток, который и так мертвый из за разрыва связи. а вот если с синхронизацией, то оно рушит все приложение. пока была только один раз, и не привела к падению. перенес все на 2012 сервер, тестирую дальше. как думаешь, имеет такое предположение право на жизнь ?

Comment: @Qwertiy не успел посмотреть, а файл уже недоступен.